# Surrogate Keys need to be ordered by natural key

Tags: sql, data-warehouse

Just wanted to know whether surrogate keys need to be ordered explicitly on the natural key? Does the Same surrogate key always need to be binded with the natural key when a truncate and reload is used? or does it not matter, I have some big tables that use delta load which basically just does inserts and updates. I don't want to be ordering the data to ensure surrogate key and natural key always bind if they don't need to? Isnt that why they are nonsense keys?

Answer (score 3):

The actual numeric value of a surrogate key has nothing to do with the natural key or other fields in the record. That said, once you assign a surrogate key to a record, you should never break that link or risk leaving orphaned fact records in your data.

You can see this most clearly in a slowly changing dimension table that has multiple versions of some natural keys.

`sur_key nat_key description     version valid_from  valid_through
1       105     UK Office       1       1900-01-01  2017-02-16
2       108     FR Office       1       1900-01-01  2099-12-31
3       109     NL Office       1       1900-01-01  2099-12-31
4       105     UK/IRL Office   2       2017-02-16  2099-12-31
5       102     DK Office       1       1900-01-01  2099-12-31`

As you can see, a new version of natural key 105 just gets the next surrogate key and the old record stays in place. A late arriving key 102 also just gets the next key.

Any ordering of natural keys only happens in an index on that column, never in the table itself.

Answer (score 1):

Surrogate keys and natural keys generally should not have any direct relationship.  It would be a maintenance nightmare to try to keep them aligned and you would be constantly having to re-assign the keys as new data gets added.

After a truncate and reload of your key table, your dim records may end up with a different SK, requiring your fact record to be updated/reloaded as well.

If that is a recurring scenario, you can include your natural key in the fact table.  It does take more space, but it makes reloads and troubleshooting easier.

Answer (score 0):

Inmon described a data warehouse as being a subject-oriented, **integrated**, time-variant and nonvolatile collection of data .

For implement integrated we have to understand concept of surrogate keys .

ie . We have to create DWH for an group of retail shop , so we have to pull data  Item detail data  across different shop.

```
   Shope 1 

   Item 
   Itemid  Name 
    1      Tea
    2      suger

    Sales
    orderid       Itemid   tola

    1               1      100
    2               1      100
    3               2      300

    Shope 2 

    Item 
   Itemid  Name 
    1      cofee
    2      tea

    Sales
    orderid       Itemid   tola

    1               1      100
    2               1      100
    3               2      300
```

No itemid 1 may have diffrent item across shopes , when we pull data  across shope in warehouse to with natural key (itemid), now we can not identify record  by Itemid  now we would require tow field ItemID and Shope no (Natural key + data Source identifier ).
      Now think if there is a transaction data (sales) to be pulled to establish relationship we have to join on two columns (Natural key + data Source identifier ) which will degrade performance .

second scenario you have to implement SCD then also you will required surrogate keys.

```
In nut shell surrogate keys is improve performance (read) and helps to implement [SCD][1]
```

Answer to question .

```
             Just wanted to know whether surrogate keys need to be ordered explicitly on the natural key?   no
```

Does the Same surrogate key always need to be binded with the natural key when a truncate and reload is used?  Depends on SCD implementaion 
or does it not matter, I have some big tables that use delta load which basically just does inserts and updates. 
I don't want to be ordering the data to ensure surrogate key and natural key always bind if they don't need to? you will not able to relate data
Isnt that why they are nonsense keys? read